# Does anyone know how to write this SQL If statement better?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, syntax, code-cleanup

I have this `IF` statement in my Stored Procedure:

```
if ((@someParam = 'C') OR (@someParam = 'I' AND @SomeOtherParam <> 2 AND @SomeOtherParam <> 4 AND @SomeOtherParam <> 5))
```

My question is can I check `@SomeOtherParam` in one shot, instead of having to check it 3 separate times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
if ((@someParam = 'C') OR (@someParam = 'I' AND @SomeOtherParam NOT IN (2,4,5)))
```

`IN` takes a list of values, and returns true if your value is found in the list. Adding `NOT` means that it will return true if your value is *not* found.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something with CASE statements:

```
if case @someparam when 'C' then 1 when 'I' then @someotherparam NOT IN (2,4,5) else 0 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (@SomeOtherParam  NOT IN (2, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also  [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) keyword in SQL which you can use

```
if not EXISTS (select * from list where my_column= @someotherparam )
```